# Vagrant for existing VM images / Format of metadata.json

Tags: metadata, vagrant

I have an S3 bucket of **existing** VMware virtual machine images (OVA format), and I want to make them compatible with Vagrant. However, I am a bit confused about the structure of how Vagrant images are packaged.

It seems like there are two separate `metadata.json` files that one needs to consider:

1. The `metadata.json` that goes inside of the `.box` file
2. The `metadata.json` that lists all of the `.box` files with the different providers

The Vagrant documentation talking about the [Box File Format](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format#box-file) lists a quick example for the `metadata.json`. What does make sense is that you need a `metadata.json` file to serve as an index for all of the version / provider combinations like the following:

```json
{
  "name": "hashicorp/bionic64",
  "description": "This box contains Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit.",
  "versions": [
    {
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "providers": [
        {
          "name": "virtualbox",
          "url": "http://example.com/bionic64_010_virtualbox.box",
          "checksum_type": "sha1",
          "checksum": "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This would be #2 above. But what about the `.box` file itself? What does one need to do to take an OVA (or any disk image really) and make it into a `.box` file for use in Vagrant?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out by running a test `packer` build to see exactly what it did to convert a VMware build into a Vagrant box. Turns out, the `.box` files are just compressed tarballs. Running `tar -xzf <some-box>.box` will show the contents.

```
$ tar -xvzf mybox.box

x Vagrantfile
x box.ovf
x metadata.json
x mybox.vmdk
```

The `box.ovf` and `mybox.vmdk` files are taken from the original OVA image. The `metadata.json` file simply had the JSON `{"provider":"virtualbox"}` as its contents. I'm not sure the `Vagrantfile` file is needed, but it had the following contents:

```ruby
# The contents below were provided by the Packer Vagrant post-processor

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.base_mac = "000000000000" # Original MAC address removed
end


# The contents below (if any) are custom contents provided by the
# Packer template during image build.
```

So to do what's mentioned in this ticket, all that's needed is to compress these files into a `.box` file.